# STM32F103RET6, ST-LINK V2, DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR, SWD does not work properly

Tags: debugging, stm32, microcontroller, stm32cubeide, swd

I have a custom STM32 board which has basically only the needed components to flash and use an STM32F103RET6 on board. This means, there are only a few capacitors for voltage stability, an 8MHz quarz + circuitry, and a few connectors on it.

I have the SWDIO, SWCLK and NRST lines connected through a 100 Ohms resistor exposed to a connector, so I can use them to program the device.

Now the problem ist, that I cannot connect to the device via STM32CubeProgrammer, nor the CLI, nor my IDE of choice (Keil uVision).

When I use my ST-LINK V2, connect it to the board and my pc, and then press "connect" in the program, I get the error `DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR`.

There is literally no explanation of this error anywhere, other than "hardware issues". How can that be, if the lines are **directly** connected through a 100 Ohms resistor to the pins?

I then proceeded to try out the CLI and it didnt work either. My Keil uVision just throws the error "Internal Command Error".

So I set up a logic analyzer and found out, that the device **is actually communicating** with my ST-LINK:

**It is basically doing this:**

1. Line Reset
2. Read IDCODE (successfully)
3. Wants to write to CTRL/STAT (gets ACK WAIT as response)
4. Line Reset
5. Repeat 1-4 ca. 100 times
6. Read IDCODE
7. Read from CTRL/STAT (successfully, response: 0xF0000000)
8. Somehow stops doing anything and throws the error mentioned above.

My BOOT0 pin is floating, if that is of interest.

I have no idea how to proceed from here. I cant even connect to the device, however, the device is clearly communicating with the chip.

I checked a chip of my batch on a Evalboard (Nucleo), and it promptly connected and read the memory. So the chips are not defect.

Do I have to remove any write protection or something which the debug interface does automatically on the Nucleo-Board, or why cant I use my chip at all?

Thank you very much in advance!

This is the analysis of the SWD communication:

```
Time    Type    R/W AP/DP   Register    Request byte    ACK WData   WData details
-0.000  Line reset                          
0.000   Line reset                          
0.000   Operation   read    DebugPort   IDCODE  0xA5    OK  0x1BA01477  DESIGNER=0x477, PARTNO=0xBA01, Version=0x1
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.000   Line reset                          
0.000   Line reset                          
0.001   Operation   read    DebugPort   IDCODE  0xA5    OK  0x1BA01477  DESIGNER=0x477, PARTNO=0xBA01, Version=0x1
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.001   Line reset                          
0.001   Line reset                          
0.002   Operation   read    DebugPort   IDCODE  0xA5    OK  0x1BA01477  DESIGNER=0x477, PARTNO=0xBA01, Version=0x1
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.002   Line reset                          
0.002   Line reset                          
0.002   Operation   read    DebugPort   IDCODE  0xA5    OK  0x1BA01477  DESIGNER=0x477, PARTNO=0xBA01, Version=0x1
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Operation   write   DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0xA9    WAIT        
0.003   Line reset                          
0.003   Line reset                          
0.003   Operation   read    DebugPort   IDCODE  0xA5    OK  0x1BA01477  DESIGNER=0x477, PARTNO=0xBA01, Version=0x1
0.004   Operation   write   DebugPort   ABORT   0x81    OK  0x0000001F  ORUNERRCLR=1, WDERRCLR=1, STKERRCLR=1, STKCMPCLR=1, DAPABORT=1
0.004   Operation   read    DebugPort   CTRL/STAT   0x8D    OK  0xF0000000  CSYSPWRUPACK=1, CSYSPWRUPREQ=1, CDBGPWRUPACK=1, CDBGPWRUPREQ=1, CDBGRSTACK=0, CDBGRSTREQ=0, TRNCNT=0x000, MASKLANE=0x0, WDATAERR=0, READOK=0, STICKYERR=0, STICKYCMP=0, TRNMODE=Normal, STICKYORUN=0, ORUNDETECT=0
```

**Hardware:**

This is the hardware basically.
[image: Schematics]

Comment: you probably have stm32 copy having different id. Analyzing SWD communication makes a little or no sense in this case (it makes only sense for debug software developers). SWD works without any problems if hardware is OK.

Comment: What do you mean with copy? That its a counterfeit? As I mentioned, the same chip from the batch works on the Evaluation board. I already changed it several times. And what do you mean by different ID? I analyzed the SWD communication so that I can see what happens, the error thrown does not help in any way. I also tried a chip that came directly from a Nucleo board, and that also did not work.

Comment: And that is exactly why I ask, the SWD does not work, and I want to find out why. So your comment does not make sense in that regard.

Comment: Floating BOOT0 is problematic, but usually works. Pull it low anyway. Another possible cause is that your current firmware disables SWD. If so you either need to set BOOT0 high and BOOT1 low (just for flashing another firmware). Or you need to connect under reset (i.e. before the firmware is started and disables SWD). Other things to try: check that the oscillator actually works, check that the voltages are ok and stable. Remove the 100Ω resistors. I'm assuming that all capacitors are really close to the chip.

Comment: I have had no problems with stm32 mcus with no caps, no external crystal, etc, just power ground and some breakouts.  I do control nrst and boot0 though even though nrst doesnt need it.   in either mode for boot0 the debugger should work unless you have tried to program it once and now your code has hung the core and then you need to control boot0.  boot0 plus uart also gives you an alternate path into the chip.  (yes these are cheap breakouts to play with new to me chips and not products so lack of caps, etc is because it happens to work, if a product I would load it up with everything)

Comment: maybe remove r1, c1, c2 to isolate the crystal and control boot0 and see what happehs.  note I use openocd with telnet no gui...perhaps try that.

Comment: Check if you have connected all Vdds (including Vdda and Vbat) and all GND pins. None of them can floating.

Comment: Thank you all for your recommendation! I will try them out tomorrow right away!

Comment: I checked the oscillator. It is not working. I see no output at all. Also, pulling the BOOT0 pin high or low when starting the device does not help, the error message stays the same.

Comment: I now removed the oscillator, it does not change the error message.

Comment: I changed the 100Rs to 0Rs and it does not change the error message.

Comment: With yout newly gained experience you could take another look at AN2586. Especially chapter 2, 5 and 7. In my experience custom boards work well without any external oscillators. At least for a simple bring up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue.
The Problem was that `VDDA` pin had not enough energy supplied to it.
This means, it was a hardware issue.

To make clear what the actual problem was and why we didnt detect it:

We checked all `VDD(A)` pins and found that every pin had the right voltage supplied. However, in the gerber files we discovered that the `VDDA` pin via was not connected properly to the 3.3V plane. There was a huge resistance (in this case 600kΩ) between the 3.3V rail and the `VDDA` pin. We measured the right voltage at the `VDDA` pin because there was a capacitor and it had enough time to charge up. Thus we measured the correct voltage. However, once the uC started to draw actual power, the cap didnt provide enough energy/current and the uC couldnt start up. That also explained the error message from JLINK "Couldnt start up DAP".

Ergo: `DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR` is probably a hardware issue.